# How to get row with the maximum value by grouping

Tags: mysql

I have a table where population number is given for each day at every hour. How can I get the row with max population number? Here is an example of the table

```
date        hour population
2015-07-11  10  205
2015-07-11  11  390
2015-07-11  12  579
2015-07-11  13  679
2015-07-11  14  699
2015-07-11  15  890
2015-07-11  16  816
2015-07-11  17  970
2015-07-11  18  835
2015-07-11  19  827
2015-07-11  20  753
2015-07-11  21  638
2015-07-11  22  327
2015-07-12  9   33
2015-07-12  10  151
2015-07-12  11  227
2015-07-12  12  419
2015-07-12  13  561
2015-07-12  14  683
2015-07-12  15  799
2015-07-12  16  830
2015-07-12  17  876
2015-07-12  18  844
2015-07-12  19  819
2015-07-12  20  626
2015-07-12  21  526
2015-07-12  22  235
```

Comment: MySQL includes concepts like ordering and limiting results. See if you can make those work for you.

Comment: Try using [MAX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group.html) ?

Comment: I want the row with the max population for each day

Comment: @AhmetTanakol Edit your question accordingly.

Comment: create a fiddle for your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [MAX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group.html) to get maximum value of a column per group :

```
SELECT date, MAX(population)
FROM foo
GROUP BY date
```

**EDIT :**

If you want to have the hour that corresponds to your max population value, you can go with :

```
SELECT foo.*
FROM foo
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT date, MAX(population) as MaxPop
    FROM foo
    GROUP BY date) max
ON foo.date = max.date
AND foo.population = max.MaxPop
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well I tried it but it doesn't give me the hour. If I use hour in group by, it displays the same table not the rows with max value of population for each day at the specific hour